# bluemix containers -> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to retrieve the logs on an IBM container:

```
snowch$ cf ic logs $CONTAINER_ID
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string
```

My versions are:

```
snowch$ cf ic version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 3.0
Server API version: 1.20
Go version (server):
Git commit (server):
OS/Arch (server): Bluemix Containers/
```

and

```
snowch$ cf --version
cf version 6.18.0+b22884b-2016-05-10
```

I have seen a number of questions on stackoverflow for this error message, but none of them are using the `cf ic logs` command.

Comment: Could you try to use the new Bluemix CLI (that contains the cf 'ic' plugin too) and let me know if it works? Download link: http://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/home.html

Comment: Docs: https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest 'ic' plugin as suggested by [umberto-manganiello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397366/umberto-manganiello) fixed the issue for me.