# cf ic logs Container gives json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I can't get this working on RedHat 6.7.  It works fine on Windows but I need it from RedHat 6.7, where my Docker is older (1.7) and there doesn't seem to be a supported later one.  I get:

```
$ cf ic logs Container 
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string
FAILED
Command failed
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37175214/bluemix-containers-json-cannot-unmarshal-string-into-go-value-of-type-stri) which is identical, but says solution is to use the latest plugin.  Mine says it is there:

```
$ cf ic update
You are using the latest version of the plug-in.
```

Versions:

```
$ uname -a
Linux puvm61 2.6.32-642.15.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 20 02:26:38 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.7 (Santiago)


$docker --version
Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609

$ cf ic version
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 3.0
Server API version: 1.20
Go version (server):
Git commit (server):
OS/Arch (server): Bluemix Containers/
```

Comment: For posterity - I eventually gave up and moved to RedHat 7.3/Docker 1.10.2 where it all works perfectly.